# If $G$ acts so that $\mbox{fix}(g) \in \{0,p\}$ for $g \ne 1$. Conditions such $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ has maximal class.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a nonregular, transitive permutation group acting on $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element either fixes no point or exactly $p$ points for some prime $p$. Further suppose that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
$$
 G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\alpha}^g = 1.
$$

> If $p^2 ~ | ~ |\Omega|$ and $p ~ | ~ |G_{\alpha}|$, does this imply that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ have maximal class?

A $p$-group of order $p^{k+1}$ has maximal class, if its nilpotency class is $k$, see for example [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_class_group).

Comment: where is this action mentioned ? If you give source or provides theorems reletd to this action, it would be good.

Comment: These actions are considered in a series of papers by O. Pretzel & A. Schleiermacher with the aim at classifying all groups that have certain restrictions on their fixed points. Some properties of groups as mentioned in the questions: (continue)

Comment: (continued)  $|N_G(G_{\alpha}) : G_{\alpha}| = p$, implying that each element of $G_{\alpha}$ fixes the same set of $p$ points, the number of non-trivial elements fixing points is $|G|(|G_{\alpha} - 1) /p|G_{\alpha}|$ and we have $\Omega \equiv p \pmod{|G_{\alpha}|}$. I have given proofs here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541146/if-g-acts-such-that-each-nontrivial-element-fixes-exactly-n-points-or-none

Comment: But what reason do you have to believe that the answer to your question might be yes (or no)? At first sight it looks like a complete arbitrary question.

Comment: It is part of an argument of a longer proof, it is directly beneath the where the following is shown: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573631/if-g-acts-such-that-mboxfixg-in-0-p-for-g-ne-1-m-maximal-wit (same reference as mentioned there in the comments) and is used in deriving that $G / L$ is not cyclic and $L$ is contained in a regular normal subgroup of $G$. Yes, it might look a little bit arbitrary, but the proof where it is stated is quite long and involved.

Comment: You need to look at the paper more carefully. You should not need to ask somebody to help you find things that are proved in the paper you are reading!

Comment: You mean it is a consequence of Lemma 1.7. of the paper; but then we have to show that the Sylow subgroups acts faithful as a group of type $(0,p)$ on their orbits. Is this implied by $p^2 \mid |\Omega|$ and $p \mid |G_{\alpha}|$?

Comment: Yes a Sylow $p$-subgroup containing a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G_\alpha$ acts faithfuly on the orbit of $\alpha$.